# Mock Masstransit's GetRetryAttempt() using NSubstitute

Tags: c#, xunit, masstransit, nsubstitute

I'm trying to mock Masstransit's GetRetryAttempt() method to return some values using NSubstitute but doesn't seems to be working. Not getting any errors but GetRetryAttempt() returns always 0 instead of 2.

**Test**

```
var context = Substitute.For<ConsumeContext<FakeCommand>>();
var consumeRetryContext = Substitute.For<ConsumeRetryContext>();
consumeRetryContext.RetryAttempt.Returns(2);
context.TryGetPayload(out consumeRetryContext).Returns(true);
context.GetRetryAttempt().Returns(consumeRetryContext.RetryAttempt);
```

**Application code**

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<T> context)
{
    ......
    var retryAttempt = context.GetRetryAttempt();
}
```

Comment: Don't mock, use the `InMemoryTestHarness` from the `Testing` namespace.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPatterson. I'm referring this https://masstransit-project.com/usage/testing.html#test-setup. Can you clarify how I can indicate my application code that retry attempt (GetRetryAttempt() should return x) is x number from the test harness?